# How to generate own secure elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I know that the algorithm used to generate the Brainpool curves and the NIST curves is published. The algorithm should be [this one (RFC5639 Appendix A)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5639#appendix-A). From what it looks like it's rather slow to find secure parameters.

After some research I've also found ["Efficient Algorithms for Generating Elliptic Curves over Finite Fields Suitable for Use in Cryptography" by Harald Baier](https://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reports/reports/harald_baier.diss.pdf) (in fact it's a PhD thesis I think) on the generation of secure elliptic curves. I've also googled around and found a tool that actually generates such curves (using this algorithm I think). From an efficiency point of view this algorithm looks faster than the NIST's one.

Now my question:
**Are the above two algorithms the only ones (published) for generating safe elliptic curves or are there other ones?**

Comment: You can refer "Standards for Efficient Cryptography 1 : Elliptic Curve Cryptography" from Certicom research for developing new curves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course there are others.  Of interest might be [the paper 'Efficient ephemeral elliptic curve cryptographic keys' by Mieli and Lenstra](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/ecc-workshop-2015/papers/session1-miele-paper.pdf), which claims to generate fresh Elliptic Curves sufficiently quickly that they can be created on the fly for a single ECDH exchange, and then discarded.

Comment: really nice and recent paper :) May I ask if this was pre-Logjam?

Comment: @SOJPM: I suspect that the ideas within the paper predated Logjam; however the paper itself is obviously recent (it references a paper published on ePrint in April).